# Ember extend component by two other components

Tags: ember.js

Assuming we have 3 components. `A`, `B`, and `C`. How to extend component `A` with functionality from component `B` and `C`?

Component `A`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import B from 'b/components/component';
import C from 'c/components/component';

export default B.extend(C, {});
```

Above example doesn't work because `C` is not a mixin. `B` and `C` come from npm (Ember CLI addons), so I can't change them.

Comment: Extract the functionality you want to share into Mixins, and then mix them into the relevant components.

Comment: @locks Do you mean copy&paste functionality from component `C` to a mixing, and then mixin it into component `A` like on my example?

Comment: You can try B.extend(c.proto(), { /* your funtionality */});

Comment: @WojciechBednarski cut the functionality from component `C` and then mix it into the component `C` and the component `A`.

Comment: @locks I can't change code of `B` and `C`. In order to make mixi from `C` I need to copy its code. As well I could just copy code from `C` directly into `A`. But this is not a solution.

Comment: Why can't you change B and C?

Comment: @locks They are external libraries. If I change their code, I can't update to the newer version easly

Comment: Hhhmm, then A can't extend both of them. Not sure what the way to go is in that case.

Comment: @WojciechBednarski have you tried to provide upstream and created a merge-request, which puts out that functionality into a mixing? Thats what I would do.